# Issue with Angular 4 Routes

Tags: angular, routes

When I execute this code to redirectTo other component

```
this.router.navigate(['/distributed-chart/' + this.invested.risk]);
```

I have this issue in console:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL 
Segment: 'distributed-chart/54f9ef8a84d534d9490002d1'
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'simulation/simulate-saving-plan', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'simulation', loadChildren: 'app/simulation/simulation.module#SimulationModule' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**simulation-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: SimulationComponent,
  children:[
    { path: 'simulate-saving-plan', component: SimulateSavingPlanComponent },
    { path: 'distributed-chart/:risk', component: DistributedChartComponent },
    { path: 'expected-rent-chart', component: ExpectedRentChartComponent },
    { path: 'historic-chart', component: HistoricChartComponent }
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class SimulationRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: this.invested.risk is not defined. You should add crucial content to your question.

Comment: with your config it sould be `this.router.navigate(['/simulation/distributed-chart/' + this.invested.risk]);` if I am not mistaken

Comment: try to write the proper url manually in the browser until you find it and then you will easily spot the mistake ;)

Comment: The problem was here =>
                      this.router.navigate(['/simulation/distributed-chart/' + 
                       this.invested.risk]);

I should add "simulation" at start of the router navigation, SOLVED!

Comment: Pro-tip: we prefer not to use the title to mark questions as solved here. The best way to do that is via an answer. I will post that for you, but if you would like to post it under your own name, ping me and I will delete my copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author)*.

The problem was here:

```
this.router.navigate(['/simulation/distributed-chart/' + this.invested.risk]);
```

I should add "simulation" at start of the router navigation, solved!